# Scrollmagic timelineMax duration offset

Tags: jquery, gsap, scrollmagic, gasp

I have a pretty simple Scrollmagic event.  It involves section wipes, as explained here - [ScrollMagic Section Wipes Example](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/section_wipes_manual.html).

So taking that I put together the following ScrollMagic setup.

```
var ctrl = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
    globalSceneOptions: {
        triggerHook: 'onLeave'
    }
});

var animationEvents = new TimelineMax()
    .fromTo($('#show .elem1'), 0.5, {opacity: '1'}, {opacity: '0', ease:Power1.easeInOut}, 0)
    .fromTo($('#show .elem2'), 1, {x: '0%'}, {x: '-100%', ease:Power1.easeInOut}, 2)
    .fromTo($('#show .elem3'), 0.5, {opacity: '0'}, {opacity: '1', ease: Back.easeOut}, 2.4)
    .fromTo($('#show .elem4'), 1, {opacity: '0'}, {opacity: '1', ease:Power1.easeInOut}, 3);

new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: '#wrapper',
    duration: '400%',
})
.setPin('#wrapper')
.setTween(animationEvents)
.addTo(ctrl);
```

So basically what I did was created a ScrollMagic controller, made my timeline of animations, and setup my scene.

It works great, no problems what-so-ever.  However, I am trying to wrap my head around a few of these values so that I can make a scrollTo function from a menu, that can scroll to each of the elements.

I have it close to working but what I cannot seem to figure out is the following; the duration of my scene is `400%` that means that as I scroll the `#wrapper` is pinned for the equivalent of scrolling past the element (in relation to my trigger) 4 times the height of the `wrapper`.

That I understand, but what I do not understand is in each element 
of the TimelineMax you have this...

```
.fromTo($('#show .elem2'), 1, {x: '0%'}, {x: '-100%', ease:Power1.easeInOut}, 2)
```

You can break it all down, but the **1** represents some sort of duration, of what I am not sure.  and the last variable, in this case **2** represents its offset of when to start.

This is my question, what do those values represent in comparison to the duration.  Since in this case I have 4 actions the first one starting at **0** and the last one finishing at a number of **4** what would make sense to me is that essentially `.elem1` starts at duration point `0%` and finishes at duration point `50%` and `elem4` starts at duration point `300%` and finishes at duration point `400%` however that does not seem to be the case, or atleast maybe the duration of `#wrapper` is not how the duration element is calculated.

At the very least I need to figure out the representation between those offset numbers within the TimelineMax and the duration.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
new TimelineMax()
    .fromTo($('#show .elem2'), 1, {x: '0%'}, {x: '-100%', ease:Power1.easeInOut}, 2)
                               ^^ --> A
                                                                                  ^^ --> B
```

**A** is the time the **animation** needs to play from start to end. (in this case it needs **one** second to move from its original to its intended position).

**B** is the **position** of the **animation** within the **Timeline**. (especially interesting when you have several **Tweens** in the same **Timeline** that shouldn't play in direct succession.) Here it means that the **animation** (the `fromTo(...)` starts **two** seconds into the **Timeline**.

The above **Timeline** now has a duration of **three** seconds.

If we apply this logic to your **Timeline** `animationEvents` we see that it has a **duration** of **four** seconds.

Now for the **ScrollMagic** part:

ScrollMagic projects the **duration** of the **Timeline** or **Tween** onto its **own duration** (the **duration** of the `ScrollMagic.Scene`).

Comment: Hey! I can't seem to get a grasp on how ScrollMagic "projects" the duration, as you say. I've written a question about it [elsewhere on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688472/how-does-scrollmagic-interact-with-timelinemax-durations). Any chance you could take a look at my question, since seem to know the answer?